Issue Linking, Building and Sharing Libraries in C++ robot.github.io
I am having issues linking/building libraries.
gcc -o main main.o -lmmath -L.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmath: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

my_math
|-- my_math.c
main.c
libmy_math.so


Welcome to SO. mmath != my_math

To be clearer, replace -lmmath with -lmy_math.
